# Azure Gov Cloud and Azure Functions trigger on Storage

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-gov

I have hard time with Azure Functions on Azure Government. I need to create a C# trigger bases process on Azure Storage. The goal is to automate the process of the loading the files into Azure SQL DB when a file is dropped into Azure Storage.

Since Azure Functions in Azure Government are not fully comparable to Azure Function in regular Azure and not all UIs are the same, I can't deploy the function to trigger on a storage file.

I was able to build the process in regular Azure Cloud following instructions from https://github.com/yorek/AzureFunctionUploadToSQL but since Azure Government is missing the UI for Azure Functions I'm having hard time to replicating the process in Azure Government.

Answer (score 2):

Portal UI support is not yet available in Azure Government, but [it is coming soon](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/558487-azure-government/suggestions/32686675-azure-functions-ui-in-azure-government). Additionally, Azure Government currently supports "App Service plan" ("Consumption plan" coming soon).

In the meantime, you can do everything you need. First, **provision your Azure Function in Azure Gov via the Azure CLI** by following [this Quickstart example for Functions on Azure Gov](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-government/documentation-government-functions). That same link also shows you how you can use Visual Studio to set up your triggers (in your case, a Blob trigger).

Once complete, **deploy your Function to Azure Gov with Visual Studio**.